# Swift-Mailer error, "Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC"

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I have built a simple PHP contact form that is supposed to send mail trough the Swift-Mailer script.

Problem is I keep getting this error

> Uncaught exception
>   'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with
>   message 'Address in mailbox given []
>   does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'

Which I guess means I am using an invalid e-mail address. But since I am using myaddress@gmail.com to test the scrip the problem is probably somewhere else. This is my configuration:

Where the mail is sent to:

```
$my_mail = 'mymail@mydomain.com';
$my_name = 'My Name';
```

The content of the message:

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); 
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  

$content = $message.'\n\nSent on: '.$date.' From: '.$ipaddress;
```

The function i use to send the mail using swiftmailer:

```
function send_mail () {
require('/path/to/swift_required.php');

//The means of transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.mydomain.com', 25);
$transport->setUsername('myusername');
$transport->setPassword('mypass');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//The message
$mail = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$mail->setSubject('Hello');
$mail->setFrom(array($email => $name ));
$mail->setTo(array($my_mail => $my_name));
$mail->setBody($content, 'text/plain');

//Sending the message
$test = $mailer->send($mail);

if ($test) {
    echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us '.$name.'! We will get in touch soon.</p>';
}
else {
          echo '<p>Something went wrong. Please try again later.</p>';
}
}
```

As you can see it is really simple form with three fields, name, mail and message. I also have other validation set up for each of contact form fields, but I think it is of little concern here.

Thank you for the help.

Edit:
Just test with using gmail as the smtp server. Unfortunately it still  gives the same exact results.

Comment: Dump out the content of `$email` and `$my_email` after you've done your trim/htmlspecialchars/strip_tags work and see what they looks like. The swiftmailer code itself looks ok, so possibly the addresses are getting mangled somewhere before they reach swiftmailer.

Comment: And remove both, `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars`. Those two functions are not designed to work with email addresses and names but with HTML. I think you're mixing concepts here. Do proper escaping, not brain-dead escaping. Know what you do and why!

Comment: @Marc_B That was what i suspected also. But they were correct... My other guess is could the error refer not to the sent to address but the receiver address? i will try testing with a gmail address as receiver and with gmail smtp server as well...

Comment: @hakare ok I left only the trim function, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your data variables (addresses, names...) appear to be global. Global variables cannot be read from within functions unless you pass them as parameters (the recommended way) or use the `global` keyword (or the `$GLOBALS` array).

Comment: but how to define global varialble in `Mail::send('filename' , $data, function($message)) { ....` ?

Comment: @TarangP My tip is that you forget about globals, they just make code harder to write and maintain.